# UWP connection to MySql

Tags: uwp

My app is 100% working when I compile and run it stright from Visual Studio. Unfortunately, when I create App Package my app cannot connect to MySQL database. I have no idea what's going on, I can't even find any docs about this. Do I need more capabilities? My app targets 1803 with minimal Fall Creators Update.

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: The UWP app can not connect the localhosts 127.0.0.1

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that. Thank you.